# How to implement "you might also want to follow"

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to follow twitter accounts, I would like to know how to implement "`you might also want to follow`" and "`similar to @foo`" using `twitter4j API`.

Is there a way to fetch this information dynamically using this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for suggested user list, you should look [UserMethods Interface](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/index.html?twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html) that has the method

```
ResponseList<User> getUserSuggestions(java.lang.String categorySlug)
                                      throws TwitterException
```

This method should match with the Twitter API [GET users/suggestions/:slug](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/suggestions/%3Aslug)

Since [Twitter Interface](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html) is sub interface of that, you could call that method and get the suggested list from the user.